# Doctrine ORM, two different querys produce the same result set

Tags: php, orm, symfony1, doctrine

I'm using Doctrine 1.2 and Symfony 1.4.

In my action, I have two different query that return different result set. Somehow the second query seem to change the result (or the reference?) of the first one and I don't have any clue why..

Here is an example:

```
  $this->categories = Doctrine_Query::create()
       ->from('Categorie AS c')
       ->innerJoin('c.Activite AS a')
       ->where('a.archive = ?', false)
       ->execute();

  print_r($this->categories->toArray()); // Return $this->categories results, normal behavior.

  $this->evil_query = Doctrine_Query::create()
       ->from('Categorie AS c')
       ->innerJoin('c.Activite AS a')
       ->where('a.archive = ?', true)
       ->execute();

  print_r($this->categories->toArray()); // Should be the same as before, but it return $this->evil_query results instead!
```

Why Doctrine behave this way ? It's totally driving me crazy. Thanks!

**To make it simple it seem like the Query 2 are hijacking the Query 1 result.**

Comment: Can you show the results? What happens if you store the results of toArray(), rather than calling it on Doctrine_Collection?

Comment: jeremy: If I store the result of the toArray(), everything starts working as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the API docs for the `toArray()` method in `Doctrine_Collection` it says:

> Mimics the result of a `$query->execute(array(), Doctrine_Core::HYDRATE_ARRAY);`

I suspect to answer this question to your satisfaction you're going to have to go through the source code.

Answer (score 5):

Use something like this between queries (`$em` - entity manager):

```
$em->clear(); // Detaches all objects from Doctrine!
```

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/batch-processing.html

Answer (score 0):

This seems like it has to be an issue of $this->categories and $this->evil_query pointing to the same place. What are the results of `$this->evil_query === $this->categories` and `$this->evil_query == $this->categories`?

Answer (score 0):

Hubert, have you tried storing the query into a separate variable and *then* calling the `execute()` method on it?

I mean something like:

```
$good_query = Doctrine_Query::create()
  ->from('...')
  ->innerJoin('...')
  ->where('...', false)
;
$evil_query = Doctrine_Query::create()
  ->from('...')
  ->innerJoin('...')
  ->where('...', true)
;
$this->categories = $good_query->execute();
$this->evil_query = $evil_query->execute();
```

It seems like both attributes (`categories` and `evil_query`) are pointing at the same object.

Answer (score -1):

Erm, after both queries you `print_r` the result of the *first* query - change the last line to `print_r($this->evil_query->toArray());` to see the difference :)

Comment: Yes I know, the problem is that after the call to create the "evil query" the content of the first query is now the same as the second.

Comment: To be fair, that wasn't very clear from your original question.